# Windows 10 update required but windows doesn't see any new

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a problem in visual studio with bad version of windows.
Here is the problem:
[image]

But windows doesn't see any new updates.

[image]

My version
[image]

Is there any other way to force windows to update? 
I have SDK for required build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, i just needed to download new build of windows 10 and run it to update.

Answer (score 0):

You still use the Windows 10 version from July 2015, you need the November 2015 update. If Windows Update doesn't show the new version, get [the 1511 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench), mount the ISO, run `setup.exe`, select upgrade ad keep all data/software.